# How JQuery identifies whether the response is success or failure

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery. I found $.ajax() method for making ajax request. Here we add success and failure methods. But how JQuery internally finds whether the response from server is success or failure and calls the appropriate method ?

Comment: Check out the documentation - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DAjax%2FjQuery.ajax%26redirect%3Dno

Comment: It's basically just an abstraction of the browser's [XMLHttpRequest object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest), also known as [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's a failure if the AJAX request returned any HTTP status code besides `200`, or the data wasn't parsed correctly.

In the success callback you'll need to process the data to see whether it was a "success" in terms of your API call.

For example, if you send an AJAX request to register a new user, you might send something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'user/register',
    data: {user:'username'},
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
});
```

The `success` callback will fire if the response has a status of `200`, regardless of whether the server's attempt to register the user was successful.

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary things it considers for success and failure.

1. The HTTP status code
2. Whether or not the received data was able to be parsed (json, xml, etc)

Look at the [ajax events on their site](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) or at [their github page for the ajax code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js) for more details.